# is exit command in multithread programming exit completely?

Tags: c, multithreading, zombie-process

I write a program with `C`. I have 3 threads which are working concurrently. (and for protecting the critical section I use semaphore). my program exit just in some situation (ending situation which provide `i=by` `if` command) which exist in thread number 2. with command:    `exit(-1)`

When I run my program in linux, when it arrives to this condition it exit completely. But I am still not sure if all other threads exit or not? and also if they remain in memory or not? someone told me they remain as Zombie and so it could harm the system, but when I look to processes (with `ps` command) I saw nothing. Now I need some help about the kind of ending the all thread and also look for zombies in my system.

Comment: It will differ based on which OS you run your app; Linux/MacOS will kill it completely; it may remain as a zombie on windows; it might leak resources on all of them.

Comment: `exit` terminates the process, which includes all its threads. "Someone" is confusing threads with processes.

Comment: exit() will terminate all the threads in that process, because the process is terminated. However, if you have tidying up to do after you detect the ending condition, just look at [joining threads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) and gracefully join all the threads to the main one.

Answer (score 2):

`exit` terminates the whole program, no threads are running afterwards. This might not be what you want depending on how your program is designed - no cleanup is done, threads are terminated as they are in the time of termination.